# opengl in compiz config

Tags: opengl

I was trying to sleek up Ubuntu 14.04 by disabling opengl in compiz config manager, now I only have a background!
I went into tty to reset it by typing

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```

And I get this error

```
error: cannot auto launch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY

Usage:
   dconf reset [-f]  PATH 

reset a key or dir.  -f is required for dirs.

Arguments:

PATH        Either a KEY or DIR
KEY.          A key path (starting, but not ending with '/')
DIR.          A directory path starting and ending with '/')
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you have internet acces you can fix this using `compiz-config-settings-manager`.
Unfortuantely you are unable to login in your normal enviroment. So in order to fix that we need to install the `gnome-session-flashback`.

## **Step 1:Installing Gnome Desktop**

Make sure that you have internet acces for this step!

1. Boot up your pc
2. When you get to the login screen, press ctrl-alt-f2
3. You are now in tty
4. Log-on with your username and password
5. As soon as you are logged on execute the following command: `sudo apt-get install gnome-session-flashback`, this will install two old gnome versions, Compiz and Metacity.
6. After installing `gnome-session-flashback` logout.
7. After logging out, press ctrl-alt-f7.
8. At this point you will notice a button on your login screen on the top right, click it.
9. Here you can choose your session manager. I think you have to choose metacity, but don´t count me on that one.
10. After logging in, you can open a terminal by pressing ctrl-alt-t

## **Step 2: Fixing the system**

1. When in your working terminal session, execute `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`.
2. After the command executes, run `ccsm`.
3. When it opens up, read the warning,
4. In the section 'General' there is a button with OpenGl next to it. Click the button to re-enable OpenGL again.

## **A completely different way**

After you login in tty, you can also install `compiz-config-settings-manager` straight away, but then you will be unable to execute it, as your session manager (Unity, I assume?) doesn't work with the tty terminal. The tty terminal, as such doesn't know which screen to output it to.

However if you execute the following commands:

```
set display=:0
ccsm
```

You will get the same window as in step two.

**After you are done with repairing, reboot your computer.**